# Spotfire: Calculate delta between two filtered series

Tags: calculated-columns, difference, spotfire

I must calculate a delta between two time series, based on filtering over one column.

Here's the situation, I've got a table like this:

[image: table]

The user chooses a reference Id with a dropdown list, and the string is stored in document property ReferenceId.

I want a calculated column that will dynamically calculate the difference between the current row value and the corresponding reference row value. For instance, if ReferenceId=Id1:

[image: table2]

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reference year to get the correct value... This should work

```
100*([Value]-First(case when "${ReferenceId}"=[Id1] then [Value] end) over [Year])/First(case when "${ReferenceId}"=[Id1] then [Value] end) over [Year]
```

Comment: It works fine, thank you ! (just replace "Id1" by "Id")